# I want to auto animation in image view like flipboard cover page in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-activity, uiviewanimation

In my app i want to make automatic animation which is like flipboard cover (first) page animation in android app. please help me this this case i am sharing screen shot of flipboard animation image.

I am Using TranslateAnimation. but is not look like flipboard.

```
ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration 
animation.setRepeatCount(5);  // animation repeat count
animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animation.setZAdjustment(100);
animation.setFillAfter(true);       

img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
```

[image]

second image is here. 
[image]

[image]
Here We can see. ony one image is animate in tablet left to right.

Comment: Thanks for ans. But 
First read all question. I dont need that android-flip. I have already that code. I want to make autoanimate. as flipboard first Start page.

Comment: @WhiteLion do you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340396/how-to-flip-images-like-3d-animation-in-android like this ?

Comment: Yes I am with you. but that is flip animation . in side the app. Please see Image i am again upload with change that and make easy .

Comment: You also see my code. may be you understand some thing from that.